# Persisting Checkbox state while paging in SPGridView

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, persistence, session-state, aspxgridview

Suppose I have created a spgridview with the following code.

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="spgridList" Visible="false" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true" PageSize="5"
                        OnPageIndexChanging="spgridList_PageIndexChanging" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Red"
                        onrowdatabound="spgridList_RowDataBound" onrowcommand="spgridList_RowCommand">
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="ms-descriptiontext" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="true" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox CssClass="chkbox" Checked="false" ID="chkField" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="chkField_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

To persist the checkbox states between pagebacks ,currently i am using session states.It has some draw backs.Now how can I persist the checked states,when the user manually checks all the checkboxes,how can i make a check on the header checkbox?Provide some links

Answer (score 0):

How about emulating it like a select CheckBox but disabling the focus of the row?

Selection of the rows is maintained across pages.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1559.aspx